# Batch - error when loading from a file

Tags: batch-file

I have been having problems when loading from a file, I cant seem to find the problem since it is working everywhere else in my code. 
Anyways here is the code

```
set /p viewsave= 
if exist save%viewsave%.txt (
set /p level=<save%viewsave%.txt
echo save%viewsave%
echo you are on level %level%
pause
```

it can find save%viewsave% and I know that it knows that level = 0 because when using echo it says

```
set /p level= 0<save1.txt
```

but it does not echo it when I echo

```
you are on level %level%
```

it just does not display anything

here is an example of where it somehow did work

```
set /p saves=<savesnr.txt
echo you have %saves% saves
```

Comment: Use [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and `echo you are on level !level!`

Comment: This worked can you write it under answers so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Answer written.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and replace:

```
echo you are on level %level%
```

With:

```
echo you are on level !level!
```

---

#### EnableDelayedExpansion

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be
>   expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is
>   turned on with the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` command.
>
> When delayed expansion is in effect variables can be referenced using
>   `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal `%variable_name%` )
>
> When a batch file is executed, the command processor (CMD.exe) will
>   parse complete lines and complete compound commands. Variables are
>   replaced by their values just once, BEFORE the commands of the line
>   are executed.

Source [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.